# Can't pip install from a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to pip install `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/lapu/simple fix-yahoo-finance` but every time I do so, a whole bunch of red text comes out and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm using Windows and Anaconda, I've already installed pip prior to this. Any advice?

The error is as follows:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 410, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 304, in get_connection
    proxy_url = parse_url(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Cecilia\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\url.py", line 199, in parse_url
    raise LocationParseError(url)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: host:port
```

Comment: why are you trying to install from the external repository? why not just `pip install fix-yahoo-finance`?

Comment: FWIW I tried creating a virtualenv and installing the package. After I installed all the dependencies, your command worked for me. This is not using Anaconda, though, and not Windows either.

Comment: @wpercy I'm following the instruction according to https://anaconda.org/lapu/fix-yahoo-finance, but yes I have tried that as well, it returns the same error message that I've pasted above. I'm thinking if i should try manually installing since I've been stuck trying for hours already...

Comment: Look at your `~/.pip/pip.conf`, may be there is a broken URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing like specified on the [Github page](https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance) ?

```
$ pip install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Yes I have, it returns the same error message as pasted above. It's as though trying to 'pip install' is the problem...

Comment: @HannahTang Have you tried using a other install than Anaconda, such as [pip-win](https://pypi.org/project/pip-Win/) also ? I do not have any experience with either, but it might be worth the try. Also, since installs, maybe try rebooting to clear any possible temporary local bugs for which we could not anticipate.